# Access React context value from redux-saga function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga, react-context

I have some variables which are controlled by React Context through React.createContext() with Provider and Consumer component. I'm also using redux-saga, so my question is are there anyway to access this context value in redux-saga function. I'm looking for something like "yield select" statement that works with redux-store.

Anyone who know it please explain to me. Thank you in advances.

P/S: Currently, I pass context value to action object payload when dispatch an action. So in redux-saga, we can use it in action parameter. I don't know whether it's the best practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***EDIT:*** There is now a package that allows you to grab context easily, [react-outside-call](https://github.com/alisternorris/react-outside-call)

You can keep an outside reference of your provider component, and grab the state from that.

Something like this...

Provider component

```
class AppProvider extends Component {
  state = {
    number: 10,
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <AppContext.Provider value={this.state}>
        {this.props.children} 
      </AppContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

Apps main entry file, or where ever you reference that provider instance.

```
let appProviderRef
export const getProviderState = () => appProviderRef.state

ReactDOM.render(
  <AppProvider ref={ref => appProviderRef = ref}>
    <App />
  </AppProvider>
, document.getElementById('root'))
```

You can now grab the state from within your redux sagas (or anywhere you want) synchronously calling `getProviderState`

Comment: the whole point of context is to provide alternative values for specific sub trees, as far as I know this only get the first value of the context, it could just use normal js module variable and import on demand.

Comment: But how about if I need to access the real react context (e.g router context...)?