# Access context api in sagas

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-context

I have some variables which are controlled by React Context through React.createContext() inside a functional component. I'm also using redux-saga, so my question is are there anyway to access this context value in redux-saga function.  Storing the values in Saga middleware isn't an option bcoz, the context values keeps changing.

The only option I have is to pass the context value to action object payload when dispatch an action. So in redux-saga, we can use it in action parameter.

I have visited this link for Class component, which doesnt work for Functional components.
[Access context data in sagas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57694451/access-react-context-value-from-redux-saga-function)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I finally created a package to get around this, just use useContext when creating the call config.

https://github.com/alisternorris/react-outside-call